# How do I patch Hydra to run large wordlists?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I am on a Kali Linux 2019.1a 64-bit Live USB 128GB with Persistance. My normal OS is Windows 10 Pro. My question is...How do I patch Hydra or Kali to allow larger wordlists? Bigger than rockyou? I have crackstation. I read to try this script below but I don't know where to put it. So how do I use large wordlists (15GB)? Where do I enter the script? Please reply. Thanks

split -l MAX_LENGTH --additional-suffix=".lst" words.lst words_

for user in words_*.lst
do
for pass in words_*.lst
do
hydra [[options] ...] -L "${user}" -P "${pass}" [[args] ...]
done
done
rm -v words_*.lst

Comment: Well, the split command will generate the files. I recommend you _dont_ delete the files after splitting them, since every time you will have to re-split the files. In any case, put them in a .sh file (myscript.sh for eg), run `chmod +x myscript.sh` and then run it by ./myscript. Save this script anywhere you'd like

Comment: I will try that. I'm using a new USB persistence. In the past I've used VMware and Windows 10 Host. I read on Kali Forums a member said that there shouldn't be any size problems. I'd like to try again. That'd be nice. I can only get rockyou.txt working. On VMware Burp freezes and Hydra says it can't use over 50,xxx etc...I will definately try splitting. Do you know if they have no size limits? Do you use splitting? Thanks

Comment: I haven't used those programs in particular, but if they need splitting then you should split them and save that in your persistent storage (probably just your normal documents etc). Then it should persist, as should the scripts you've made from those commands